# Modifying the Property for an existing firewall configurations with Azure Bicep

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-bicep

Currently deployed the following Azure Firewal with Firewall Policy. But I would like to add one more firewall policy by modifying the existing Firewall implementation.

```
resource resAzureFirewall 'Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls@2021-02-01' = if (parVirtualHubEnabled && parAzFirewallEnabled) {
  name: parAzFirewallName
  location: parLocation
  tags: parTags
  zones: (!empty(parAzFirewallAvailabilityZones) ? parAzFirewallAvailabilityZones : json('null'))
  properties: {
    hubIPAddresses: {
      publicIPs: {
        count: 1
      }
    }
    sku: {
      name: 'AZFW_Hub'
      tier: parAzFirewallTier
    }
    virtualHub: {
      id: parVirtualHubEnabled ? resVhub.id : ''
    }
    additionalProperties: {
      'Network.DNS.EnableProxy': '${parAzFirewallDnsProxyEnabled}'
    }
    firewallPolicy: {
      id: (parVirtualHubEnabled && parAzFirewallEnabled) ? resFirewallPolicies.id : ''
    }
  }
}
```

The following is the target policy needs to be added for the above Firewall.This is the new firwall policy that I wanted to add to the main firewall or within this policy, I would like to add the main firewall as parent.

```
resource workloadFWPolicy 'Microsoft.Network/firewallPolicies@2022-07-01' = {
  name: workloadFwPolicyName
  location:parLocation
  properties: {
    sku: {
      tier: 'Premium'
    }
    threatIntelMode: 'Alert'
    basePolicy: {
      id: platformFwPolicy.id
    }
    intrusionDetection: {
      mode: 'Off'
    }
  }
}
```

I am unable to delete the existing firewall and re-create as new due to complexity of the existing configurations.Firewall policy api does not have the property to add a firewall as a parent in the policy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/firewallpolicies?pivots=deployment-language-bicep